# In Julia, How do you check, list, update your packages?

Tags: package, julia

I'm wondering if there are utility commands in Julia that perform simple package management operations, such as:

- List a single or all packages installed
- Upgrade a single or all packages installed
- Remove a package or all packages
- Clean up package remnants

These are commands that I frequently use in yarn or homebrew for example and I was wondering if there were equivalents in Julia?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
using Pkg
Pkg.update()
Pkg.status()
Pkg.rm("PackageName")
```

This is all [in the Julia manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/).

Comment: Nitpicking, but since this seems to be what the user is after, technically the "upgrade" command is more the process of doing a Pkg.update(), Pkg.build(), and possibly [triggering a re-precompilation for the affected packages so that they're ready to use](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/16409).

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought to look in the manual! It simply did not occur to me after a quick Google search for "check installed Julia packages" didn't turn up much.

Comment: The julia manual is a surprisingly useful document. I used R for years and got into the habit of googling instead of using the manual, but in Julia it really is the first-resort reference.

Comment: This is no longer valid in v1.0. At least `Pkg.installed()`